# mysql and rspec bug

Tags: mysql, ruby, rspec

In Sequel Pro,  created a table using this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dogs(
id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name TEXT,
color TEXT
);
*auto increment, under extra in structures, is checked so Sequel Pro generate primary keys automatically*
```

Using mysql2, I author the method insert, in ruby file classdog.rb, to insert a new dog into Table dogs.

classdog.rb is below in its entirety:

```
require 'mysql2'
require "debugger"

class Dog
  attr_accessor :name, :color, :id,

  @@db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :username => 'root', :database => 'dogs')


  def initialize(name, color)
    @name = name
    @color = color
  end

  def self.db 
    @@db
  end

  def db 
    @@db
  end

  def insert 
    db.query("INSERT INTO dogs(name, color) VALUE('#{name}', '#{color}')")
  end
end

dog = Dog.new("simba", "grey") 
puts dog.insert
```

To check if my code is working, I create this rspec file:

```
require "./classdog"

describe Dog do

  describe "#insert" do
    it "should insert a dog into the database" do
      dog = Dog.new("simba", "grey")
      sql_command = "SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE name = '#{dog.name}'";
      row_hash = {"id" => 1, "name" => "simba", "color" => "grey"}
      expect(Dog.db.query(sql_command).first).to eq(row_hash) 
    end
  end
end
```

When I run my spec file in ruby using this command:

```
rspec spec_classdog.rb
```

My tests passes.

But there 2 things I don't understand:

1. The table itself only inserts a new dog when I run my spec file, **spec_classdog.rb**, using rspec. But when I run my ruby file, **classdog.rb**, no new dog is inserted.

   - Why is this happening? I expected that running my ruby file could result in new insertions while rspec is just to check to make sure that my method works. It is because I am not passing the parameters name and color to insert method (meaning something like this: dog.insert("spot", "black")?
2. When I have the following code in my classdog.rb file:

   ```
   dog = Dog.new("simba", "grey")
   puts dog.inspect
   puts dog.name
   puts dog.color
   puts dog.id
   ```

Ruby puts: 
[image: result]

Notice that dog.id has no output, as seen very clearly below:

```
    dog = Dog.new("simba", "grey") 
    puts dog.id
```

[image: noID_revealed]

- why isn't ruby revealing the the id of dog in dog.id?
- Is it because id was set as a primay key when the TABLE dog was created?
- Will adding a specific column named **dog_id** help?

@PeterAlfvin: here is an image showing output of running `puts dog.insert`
[image: Nothing is Displayed]

Comment: You're writing your own ORM here and making a lot of serious mistakes. [Proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) is not optional. Why would you go this route rather than using [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) or [Data Mapper](http://datamapper.org/)? You should not be using string interpolation to compose queries, it's completely reckless. Writing directly against the `mysql2` library is not recommended.

Comment: If you're looking to do this as an academic exercise, that's great, but be extra super careful when writing queries.

Comment: @tadman: This is purely an academic exercise BUT I still would like to  know how things are done in practice (would rather pick up good habits than bad). 
Will look up proper escaping and Data Mapper; haven't learnt rails yet so no ActiveRecord. 

Would appreciate it if you can give feedback on my questions. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you believe the database insertion is not taking place when you simply run classdog?

Comment: Each time I simply run classdog.rb, i refresh my table and I don't see any changes. When I run rspec spec_classdog.rb, I refresh my table and I see that a new dog has been added to the table.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: I am relatively new to programming and still learning a lot of terms so I have to (shamefully) admit that I am not entirely sure which environment I am looking at. I think its my test because its on my local server and its not deployed to any platform. If this is true, then I don't have a development platform yet. Am I right?

Comment: What console output do you get when you run the version of classdog that you've shown in your question (i.e. the version with `puts dog.insert`)?

Comment: I apologize to you, actually. That previous comment of mine (i.e. about development vs. test environment) would only have applied if you were running Rails, which you are not. I deleted the comment.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: its all right; its my job to make sure my questions are understood explicitly … and not make reviewers work harder:)  I will update the question to include an image of my console output (it outputs nothing actually).

Comment: That was another not-so-bright question on my part, as I don't know what `db.query` _should_ return on a successful `insert`.

Comment: read the documentation for the gem doing the connection (mysql2) and believe it is returns the result of issuing the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's at least some of your problems:

- Mysql doesn't auto-create primary key columns for you unless you specify `auto_increment` on the column
- The `insert` method does not provide an `id` value, so it will always fail, since `id` is required to be non-null.
- Given the above, any entries in your database were not created by the code you've shown.

Given that you've addressed that issue, then you've got the following:

- The `id` value is only being created by mysql in the *database*, not in the Ruby `Dog` object, so it will always be `nil` in the object unless/until you set it (which you are not currently doing).
- It has nothing to do with `id` being a primary key
- Creating a `dog_id` attribute/column/field would have not effect on this
- Ruby *is* revealing the value of `dog.id`; it's string representation just happens to be the empty string

Comment: forgot to add that AUTO_INCREMENT is MARKED in Sequel Pro.

Comment: Ok. You should update your question, as that's pretty important. ;-)

Comment: Hi @Peter will this:

def new_from_hash(hash)
    Dog.new(hash["name"], hash["color"]).tap {|dog| dog.id == hash["id"]}
  end:

take care of setting/creating id value in Ruby Dog object?

Comment: No, and SO comments are not really an acceptable way to present code for review. I suggest you "close out" this SO question when you're satisfied with the answers you've already posed and use a separate question if you want feedback on how to create/maintain the id field.

Comment: Will do now. Thanks for all your feedback; really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why a running `spec spec_classdog.rb` results in the inserting of a new dog is because my rspec file contains sql statements - therefor running rspec file results in sql statement begin carried out.

My rb file does not contain any rspec statements - classdog.rb simply exists to tell each dog object what I want it to do in Ruby-land. Also remember that in Ruby-land dog objects disappear after it is created & has carried out its call; it does not persist. Hence the need for database - resolves the issue of persistence.

See [this link]: [How to create/maintain ID field in Sequel Pro via Ruby and mysql2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670481/how-to-create-maintain-id-field-in-sequel-pro-via-ruby-and-mysql2) for answer to the 2nd part of the question.