# How to create/maintain ID field in Sequel Pro via Ruby and mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

In Sequel Pro,  created a table using this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dogs(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name TEXT,
color TEXT
);
```

Since the `id` value is being created by MySQL, I would like to set/create/maintain the `id` field in ruby so that `puts dog.id` will not be an empty string.

Was wondering if this piece of code would accomplish that:

```
def new_from_hash(hash)
    Dog.new(hash["name"], hash["color"]).tap {|dog| dog.id = hash["id"]}
end
```

NOTE: I am not running rails; just plain ruby, the gem mysql2, and Sequel Pro.

Thank you!

Comment: Apologies if I am misunderstanding the question, but, what is your general goal with setting the `id` field in the new `Dog` objects?

Comment: @summea and @mu:

I manually created an insert method in my classdog.rb file. This is what it looks like:

`def insert
    db.query("INSERT INTO dogs(name, color) VALUE('#{name}', '#{color}')")
  end`

I am would like to make sure that `puts dog.id` does not return an empty string, which is currently does right now.  How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe I finally figured this out.

"Since the id value is being created by MySQL, I would like to set/create/maintain the id field in ruby so that `puts dog.id` will not be an empty string."

=> because id value is automatically assigned in MySQL Ruby has no way of knowing what that id value is and therefore calling dog.id will return an empty string.

=> I need to find a way to map an objects' id value in ruby such that it is the same as the id automatically assigned to the object when I insert it in MySQL database.

=> Pay attention to the statement used to create Table dogs:

```
CREATE TABLE dogs(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name TEXT,
color TEXT
);
```

it translates to each dog create has an id (which is automatically assigned to it), a name, and a color.  There are two approaches to thinking of the storage of a dog objects' information:

```
dog = { "id" => 'some integer', "name" => "simba", "color" => "grey" }

dog = [1, "simba", "grey"]
```

I typically like to use arrays to store information but this time around I used a hash (because when I call .inspect on dog (not Dog) the result is something like this:

```
#<Dog:0x007fbf74c55068 @name="samba", @color="grey">
```

which makes me think of a hash data structure:

```
{ "id"=> 1, "name"=>"simba", "color"=>"grey"}
```

In Ruby, I do this:

```
def row_hash(hash)
  hash={}
  Dog.new(hash[name], hash[color]).tap { |id| id = hash[id] }
end
```

Where hash_row refers to the row that holds each dog object's attribute. This basically lets Ruby know that each time it instantiates a new instance of the class Dog it should tap into that instantiation and map hash[id] to "id".

Doing this allows me to access the value of "id" in ruby.

PS: This just occurred to me. I probably will edit this answer after it percolates for a while.